# IoC container for Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, ioc-container, caliburn.micro

I will be developing a new WPF application. I decided to use Caliburn.Micro for my MVVM so would like to ask you which one of the known IoC containers is the best approach with WPF Caliburn.Micro framework based on yours opinion or experience ? And if you could say why is that.

Thanks

Comment: There is an [IoC container](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Simple%20IoC%20Container&referringTitle=Documentation) included with Caliburn Micro...Please refer to the Creation & Lifecycle section of [this doc](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator)

Comment: If I don't want to use that one ;)

Comment: `Autofac` has its own bootstrapper for `Caliburn.Micro` available from nuget as `Caliburn.Micro.Autofac`.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use Unity together Winther caliburn.micro on my current projekt. It Works really great

Comment: Ok, thanks. Has anyone thought of using Autofac?