# Reusing view instances with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I have got a view containing sub-views with ContentControls like this

```
<ContentControl x:Name="DetailView" />
```

This works fine. When I change the contents for the `ContentControl` to another ViewModel it will load the other ViewModel and view. But when I change back to the ViewModel from before it will not reuse the view instance but create a new one. Note: I do not assign a new instance of the first ViewModel but excatly the same one.

How can I say Caliburn.Micro to reuse the instance of the view from before rather than creating a new view instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[What IoC container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961673/ioc-container-for-caliburn-micro) do you use to create instances of `View` and `ViewModels`?

Just create a single instance of `<ContentControl/>`. Let me show how to create a singleton in IoC container `Unity`:

```
container.RegisterType<IViewContentControl, ConentControl>(
                        new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

where `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()` means that there is just **one instance in the whole lifecycle** of your application.

Comment: I am using the `SimpleContainer` from the Caliburn.Micro framework itself. I had only setup ViewModels in the container yet. Thanks to your input I can see that the View models can be generated through the `IoC` container too. So I just need to register the View too: `container.Singleton<MyView>();` - but if the ViewModel would be `PerRequest`, could every ViewModel have a `1:1` relationship with a View?

Comment: @ZoolWay no, if you register your view as singleton, it does not mean that its view model automatically be registered as singleton. You should register `viewModel` as singleton too.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear - I am going ViewModel first so I already have defined the ViewModel as IoC-singleton and doing this for quite a while. Having the view setup via IoC too was the new part to me ;)

Comment: The open question is: If the viewmodel is per-request and the view is singleton, will there be one view per viewmodel-instance (when going viewmodel-first) or will there be one single-view shared accross all viewmodel instances?

Comment: **Will there be one view per viewmodel-instance (when going viewmodel-first)?** yeah, there will be just one **single instance** of `View` for newly created `ViewModel`. However, `DataContext` property of `Window` can be set for one viewModel at one time. You want to have multiple ViewModels for one View?

Comment: Nope, that way everything is fine.

Comment: It is better to create one `ViewModel` for one `View`. For example `ViewModelA` for `ViewA`. Just create a singleton instance or create just one time a `ViewModel` by IoC container .